How to modify and test a android kernel on a real phone?
I am a student in the field of information engineering, and for research purposes, I need to modify the kernel of my Pixel 5a phone and perform some debugging.
Objective
Currently, I am trying to display debug information for the network part of the kernel on my Pixel 5a (by adding printk and using dmesg).
Have already do

I built AOSP, which took up a lot of space and time. Then I found that it seems possible to directly download the Android kernel file, so I got the android-msm-redbull-4.19-android13-qpr2 file and compiled it.

I tried to modify /Project/android_kernel/private/msm-google-modules/wlan/qcacld-3.0/core/mac/src/pe/lim/lim_process_deauth_frame.c and /Project/android_kernel/private/msm-google/net/mac80211/tx.c by adding printk to see if the modification was successful.

My build code is as follows:
BUILD_CONFIG=private/msm-google/build.config.redbull BUILD_BOOT_IMG=1 MKBOOTIMG_PATH=mkbootimg.py KERNEL_BINARY=Image.lz4 BOOT_IMAGE_HEADER_VERSION=3 KERNEL_CMDLINE="" BASE_ADDRESS=0x00000000 PAGE_SIZE=4096 CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc build/build.sh -j8，This gave me an out folder containing many .ko files and image files.

According to online tutorials, I chose an image file to burn with the following code:fastboot flash boot boot.img，The phone can be turned on and off normally, but when I use dmesg to check the logs, no changes have occurred. How should I modify it to debug my code?


